# Infer generic type argument from function callback

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given a function `foo`, the  type parameter `T` is properly inferred as `string` in this case:

```
declare function foo<T>(callback: (bar: T) => void): void

// foo<string>(callback: (bar: string) => void): void
// ---> T is inferred string here
foo((bar: string) => { })
```

However the following sample shows `T` to be inferred as `unknown`. So my question is: Why doesn't the type resolve with `T` nested inside an object type of the callback?

```
declare function foo2<T>(callback: (bar: { a: T }) => void): void

// foo2<unknown>(callback: (bar: { a: unknown; }) => void): void
// ---> T is inferred unknown here
foo2(({ a: string }) => { })
```

[Sample code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=29#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVAPgAowoIIAjKMAawC54KGY2SBKeAXjLwAbjizAebUeIBQiQhQ6w2AZwwwsqAOZ9B8AN7wAvjxkzQkWAhTpseAjgBMpStVoNmbJVwPwo3Y10haQkpMWA5QkdFQ394NQ1tQIEhQxMgA)

Comment: Looks like a typo to me... you're accidentally using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) to create a *local variable* named `string`, which is not what you want.  (Note that `foo2(({ a: monkey }) => { })` is not an error, because `monkey` is a variable name, not a type name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
declare function foo<T>(callback: (bar: T) => void): void
foo((bar: string) => { })

declare function foo2<T>(callback: (bar: T) => void): void
foo2((a: { a: string }) => {} )
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=32&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVAPgAowoIIAjKMAawC54KGY2SBKeAXjLwAbjizAebUeIBQiQhQ6w2AZwwwsqAOZ9B8AN7wAvjxkzQkWAhTpseAjgBMpStVoNmbJV3i8BQ6QkpMWA5QkdFKDZDKPg1DW1jXSF9I3geIA)